# http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" and IE - 9 compatibility view - site crashes

Tags: crash, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

I added this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in to my header.

In IE 9 my browser crashes if I add the domain of my site in to the compatibility view list of the browser and then I call my website.

Also the browser crashes if I work on IE 11 and I am going to browsermode 9.

I have to add this meta tag.
What can I do?
Where do I wrong?

additional:

I found out that this meta tag doesn`t work well in combination with this part of script:

```
window.CSSHover = (function(){

    var REG_INTERACTIVE = /(^|\s)((([^a]([^ ]+)?)|(a([^#.][^ ]+)+)):(hover))/i,
        REG_AFFECTED = /(.*li?|.*ul?)\:(hover)/i,
        REG_PSEUDO = /[^:]+:([a-z-]+).*/i,
        REG_SELECT = /(\.([a-z0-9_-]+):[a-z]+)|(:[a-z]+)/gi,
        REG_CLASS = /\.([a-z0-9_-]*on(hover))/i,
        REG_MSIE = /msie (5|6|7|8|9)/i,
        REG_COMPAT = /backcompat/i;

    var CSSHOVER_PREFIX = 'csh-';

    var CSSHover = {
        elements: [],
```

I am calling this script in the body with: `[%- IF BROWSER=="MSIE" AND BROWSERVERSION < "9.0" -%]style="behavior: url(/css/csshover.h);" [%- END -%]`

```
    callbacks: {}, 
    init:function() {
        if(!REG_MSIE.test(navigator.userAgent) && !REG_COMPAT.test(window.document.compatMode)) return;

        var sheets = window.document.styleSheets, l = sheets.length;
        for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
            this.parseStylesheet(sheets[i]);
        }
    },
```

Comment: do you have any error message when ie crash or it just closes? what happen when the domain is not in the compatibility list? what about other browsers? they work ok? why you have to add this tag?

Comment: ie crashes and I got a window with "Website" is not responding.. and the site is loading and loading..